# Unable to use ssl in RHEL6 for Nexus 3.0

Tags: ssl, nexus, sonatype, rhel6

I have enabled SSL in Nexus 3.0 as described [here](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/security.html#enable-https) on a machine with RHEL6.

Before enabling SSL, I could access the Nexus from a browser using the IP-address of the RHEL6 machine from my Windows machine. However, after enabling SSL I cannot do that. I can however, access the Nexus from a browser using the same IP-address on the RHEL6 machine, so the https seems to have been enabled correctly.

Are there any other settings I need to do on RHEL to be able to make it accessible to other machines on **https**? Bot the machines are on the same network.

Comment: Does it still work via http?

Comment: Check connectivity on the same host using curl...  "curl -v --insecure https://localhost:8443", or whatever your SSL port is.  If that works, check your RHEL firewall settings, the port may be blocked.

Comment: Figured out what was the problem. Had to open the ports I was using in iptables. I'll add that as an answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The ports I was using needed to be opened in the iptables using:

`sudo iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport <portnumber> -j ACCEPT`